# In Jmeter I want to access 1000 different URL's by 1000 users concurrently ( one URL per user at the same time)

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

Using ${path} in the 'Paths:' and providing the CSV file location in the 'Filename' under CSV Data Set Config, I am able to get a single user accessing the URL's one after the other from the CSV file.

But to complete my test, I want to get 1000 users access 1000 URL's concurrently to demonstrate the maximum load on a Database server. Please advice.

I am on Jmeter5.0

Answer (score 0):

Define [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) with (default) Sharing mode All threads -

> (the default) the file is shared between all the threads.

In same hierarchy of the sampler

Define in `Thread Group` Number of Threads: 1000

And execute test while each thread get different line/values from CSV

Comment: Thanks a lot . I had made the changes on the Thread Group: Users - 1000, Rampup - 1 & CSV Data Set Config default. The CSV file had only 1000URL. I ran it and did not see any error but how to i make sure that only one URL was accessed by one user ?

Comment: @PradheepS if the Thread group's Loop Count is 1 (and not under Loop controller etc) there's no reason that sampler will be executed more than once. you can check in results

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have "bursty load":

1. Set "Number of Threads" under your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to `1000`
2. Add [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) as a child of your HTTP Request sampler and set "Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by" to `1000`

   So your test plan would look like:

   [image: JMeter Synchronizing Timer]

   It will execute 1000 requests at exactly the same moment and stop

If you want "prolonged load" - just let your Thread Group to iterate "Forever". You can limit test duration using "Scheduler" input:

[image: JMeter Thread GRoup forever]

It will execute requests with 1000 virtual users as fast as it can for 10 minutes

Comment: Synchronizing Timer - is new to me. Thanks a lot will try it.

Comment: Please stop linking to www.blazemeter.com without disclosing your affiliation with that site. This is considered spam.